# How to change AppBar Menu in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was wondering how to change Appbar Menu in `Jetpack Compose`.

In the `Fragment` world to achieve this is to do something like this:

```
class SampleFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreate(context: Context) {
        super.onCreate(context)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    // Set the R.menu.sampleMenu in the AppBar
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
        ...
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.sampleMenu, menu)
    }

    // To handle clicks on the menu
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Check id of menu item and process as follow
    }
...
}
```

I was wondering how to do the exact same thing in Compose. I was thinking of having like:

```
// Have a top level state which could be set 
var menu by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList<Menu>()) }

....
TopAppBar {
    ....
    menu.forEach {
        TextButton(...)
    }
}

....

//and then on my content ill set the `menu` to a value
onCommit {
    menu = listOf(Menu1, Menu2, Menu3, ...)
}
```

I was wondering whether this is the right way to do this or whether there is a better way.

I would love to have some inputs and advice thank you very much.

Comment: "Doing this also have a problem when navigation between screens" -- we do not know how you are performing the navigation. At least until the Jetpack Navigation component supports Compose, the most common approach that I have seen is that there is a top-level state for "what screen are we on". Changes to that state drive what composables render the screen, including what items are in the app bar menu.

Comment: But still how could the current screen capture the click event? If only the top level state hold is the identifier of the current screen?

Comment: Some composable is responsible for each of your screens. Pass in the state as a parameter to those composable functions. The idea is that the state should reside in the highest common spot, for all branches that need the state.

Comment: I kinda understand but kinda confuse. Can you show me some sample code please? I'd really appreaciate it.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I raised this concern with the Android Team... told me they'll look at it... for now you can expose a Flow<Id>, and listen to each emitted value...

Answer (score 6):

There is a component called DropdownMenu, which you can read about here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#dropdownmenu

Note that you shouldn't wrap that in a button, there is a param called toggle which will be the button to open the menu.

There is also a DropdownMenuItem, that styles as defined by the Material Design spec:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#dropdownmenuitem

About the navigation, I believe is a whole other matter, and if you have questions about that, please post other questions with details.

Here is a little sample:

```
var menuExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
DropdownMenu(
    toggle = {
        TextButton({ menuExpanded = !menuExpanded }) {
            Text("Open menu", color = Color.White)
        }
    },
    expanded = menuExpanded,
    onDismissRequest = {
        menuExpanded = false
    },
) {
    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
        Text("First item")
    }
    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {}) {
        Text("Second item")
    }
    DropdownMenuItem (onClick = {}) {
        Text("Third item")
    }
}
```

EDIT: since you commented that your issue is with sharing the app bar across screen, it's important to point out that this will behave the way you implement it to be, for instance, in the code below I would have different app bars for different screens and the issue would be solved, of course that's a very simplistic sample that wouldn't be viable with more than a few screens. But there are content out there about handling navigation in Compose and if you have issues with that, you can ask other questions scoping exactly what you need.

```
val currentScreen by viewModel.currentScreen.observeAsState(Screen.HOME)
when (currentScreen) {
    Screen.HOME -> Scaffold(/* topBar = ... */) {
        // Home body
    }
    Screen.PROFILE -> Scaffold(/* topBar = ... */) {
        // Profile body
    }
    Screen.CHAT -> Scaffold(/* topBar = ... */) {
        // Chat body
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think your answer is related to my question... hmmm..

Comment: Then I didn't understand your question, I thought you were asking how to make a menu, and I showed you that, can you explain your issue?

Comment: Its actually not about making the menu. Its was setting them and handling its `onClick` depending on the current displayed screen.

Comment: So as an example, ScreenA must have MenuA, ScreenB must have MenuB, and so on... Since the AppBar is shared across screen, how do you set these menu depending on the screen and how to handle their `onClick` events...

Comment: So, the app bar is being shared between screens because that's how you made it work, if you are using a Scaffold and placing your navigation logic in the body, the app bar really will be shared, but if you wrap your entire scaffold in your navigation logic, then you will have a app bar for each screen, I'll update my answer to cover this case

Comment: The thing is you dont want to keep rebuilding the Appbar when only a portion of it changes. When you do so, it will be quite noticeable that the AppBar gets recreated everytime. If you work with the current way Android does this, the AppBar doesn't actually change, just the menu changes.

Comment: Compose is made to be very efficient in recomposition, which means redrawing things. Devs from the Google team usually say you only need to optimize stuff that recompose several times a second or several times in a few seconds, and it's not AppBars case.

Comment: Thats is true if you are not animating things in and out. If you animate the screens that are changing it will be noticeable.